# Nested Recursion and McCarthy's 91 Function

Tags: scheme, racket

The McCarthy 91 function is a recursive function, defined by the computer scientist John McCarthy as a test case for formal verification within computer science. The McCarthy 91 function is defined as:

```
m91(n) = n − 10, if n > 100
         m91(m91(n + 11)), if n ≤ 100
```

Define a SCHEME procedure, named (m91 n), which evaluates to McCarthy’s 91 function. Try a few values for n which are less than 100 and a few greater than 100.

Not entirely sure how to include the the second conditional

```
(define (m91 n)
  (cond ((> n 100) (- n 10)
```

Comment: Hint: note that the conditions are mutually exclusive, so you could keep one of them and call the other "otherwise" (or something similar with the same meaning).

Answer (score 1):

just use `(if (> n 100) CASE-1 CASE-2)`.